# How to make a char array and 2 voids 18 times in a for loop each with different names(numbers)?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, char, void

[This is what the code looks like now](http://pastebin.com/mQqcffWS) (or at least the important bits.)

these are the (related) errors i get while compiling. (wishing i could put it in a spoiler tag)

> g15_plugin_uinput.c: In function 'g15_process_keys':
>   g15_plugin_uinput.c:189:3: error: 'g_key' undeclared (first use in
>   this function)
>
> g_key[1](http://pastebin.com/mQqcffWS)=GKEY_OFFSET+1;    ^ g15_plugin_uinput.c:189:3:  note: each
>   undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it
>   appears in g15_plugin_uinput.c:196:24:
>
> warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect
>   [-Wunused-value]    g_key[7]=KEY_LEFTMETA, KEY_F1;
>
> .....(repetition)
>
> .... (repetition ends after)
>
> g15_plugin_uinput.c:208:25: warning: left-hand operand of comma
>   expression has no effect [-Wunused-value] g_key[18]=KEY_LEFTCTRL,
>   KEY_PAGEDOWN;
>
> g15_plugin_uinput.c:208:3: warning: statement with no effect
>   [-Wunused-value]    g_key[18]=KEY_LEFTCTRL, KEY_PAGEDOWN;
>
> g15_plugin_uinput.c:292:16: error: unknown type name 'key_seq'   void
>   g_key_dn(key_seq sequences)
>
> g15_plugin_uinput.c:298:16: error: unknown type name 'key_seq'   void
>   g_key_up(key_seq sequences)
>
> g15_plugin_uinput.c:306:13: warning: implicit declaration of function
>   'g_key_dn' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>                {g_key_dn(sequences[1](http://pastebin.com/mQqcffWS));}
>
> g15_plugin_uinput.c:306:23: error: 'sequences' undeclared (first use
>   in this function)
>                {g_key_dn(sequences[1](http://pastebin.com/mQqcffWS));}
>
> g15_plugin_uinput.c:308:13: warning: implicit declaration of function
>   'g_key_up' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>                {g_key_up(sequences[1](http://pastebin.com/mQqcffWS));}

This is my desired result on for example key nr 15 if mkey_state = 0. (the if here defines the physical keypress, what's in the brackets defines what it actually does, i'm trying to automate this a little you could say. you can see lower in the code where the mkey_state changes)

```
    if((currentkeys & G15_KEY_G15) && !(lastkeys & G15_KEY_G15))
        {keydown(KEY_LEFTMETA);keydown(KEY_PAGEUP);}
    else if(!(currentkeys & G15_KEY_G15) && (lastkeys & G15_KEY_G15))
        {keyup(KEY_LEFTMETA);keydown(KEY_PAGEUP);}
```

and in the same scenario but key 1 instead of 15 i'd want

```
    if((currentkeys & G15_KEY_G1) && !(lastkeys & G15_KEY_G1))
        {keydown(GKEY_OFFSET+1);}
    else if(!(currentkeys & G15_KEY_G1) && (lastkeys & G15_KEY_G1))
        {keyup(GKEY_OFFSET+1);}
```

What did i do wrong and how can i make this code work better?

[here's a](http://pastebin.com/SYEXQDpe) bit more complete version of the code (doubt it'll help tho, it's irrelevant to the question but may give you context)

this file is sortof a plugin for a userspace keyboard driver. i already managed to make the code i desired but i'm attempting to simplify and shorten it for readability's sake, and also in the case i'd like to make an external config file later on (so i don't have to recompile everytime i want to change the bindings on the "G" extra keys.)

Comment: The two code samples differ to which is the problem related?

Comment: the one in the first line of the question. the other codesample is a bit older (before i got this far in it) it's mostly there for context of what came before the code i'm trying to write now.

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared the type of `g_key1` or anything in your code before you assign to `g_key1` to it. You need to define the type if your g_keys before you assign to them.

In order that your code works correct you need to write most likely:

```
int g_key1 = GKEY_OFFSET+1;
```

Comment: doesn't 
struct key_seq{
                
char g_key[19];
                
int seq_length;
                
};
declare all g_key[X] as a char?

Comment: no this is a local declaration not known in the code outside the brackets. It should then be `char g_key[19];` outside the struct declaration.

Comment: i don't think i get it :/ i've tried "char g_key[12] = KEY_LEFTCTRL, KEY_F6;"

It didn't seem to help at all.

Comment: You cannot assign a char to an array. Try to get your types correct. You should only assign the same types to the same types.

Comment: To initialise an array you need to enclose the list in curly brackets {}. So try `char g_key[12] = { KEY_LEFTCTRL, KEY_F6 };`

Comment: g15_plugin_uinput.c:201:8: error: conflicting types for 'g_key'
   char g_key[12] = {KEY_LEFTMETA, KEY_F6};